# How to open Script folder by using CMD

Tags: python, command-line

I want to open Script folder of python using Command prompt. I try it by copying the folders address and paste on cmd like Cd (folder address) enter
Cmd show no error or no result.

Comment: you want to open folder ? as in open windows explorer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a complete path for script folder ,
simple you have to open CMD than go to local disk (C) , click on user than the name of your account folder than you have to click on the hidden icons after that click on App Data, than Local,  than programs , than you will see a folder named python click on it. after reaching the script folder copy the whole path and paste it to cmd.

Answer (score 0):

to run python scripts from cmd you have to type

> python your_script_name.py

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna edit the scipt, `vim your_scipt.py` and to run `python your_script.py`